# Ubuntu Mate not using all its storage

Tags: ubuntu, storage

Today I bought a 32GB sd card and inserted it into my Raspberry Pi 2B. I installed Ubuntu Mate on it. Now I was installing some apps, and it says there's no more free space to install apps on. It has only used 3.6GB so far. I want to use the full 32GB. Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Ubuntu Mate Raspberry Pi [page](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/)

to re-size the file system:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
```

then delete the second partition and recreate it by selecting the following menu options:

```
 - d
 - 2
 - n
 - p
 - 2
 - enter
 - w
```

then reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

Many people find the official instructions confusing. To clarify

run `sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0`

Then press the keys in order:

**d 2** to delete,

**n p 2 Enter Enter** to re-create.

Verify the prompts to make sure what you are entering is sensible.

Reboot and enter:-

`sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2`