# Unable to expand SD Card for RT-Linux Image created using Yocto

Tags: sd-card, pi-3b+, partition, yocto

I am creating a minimal image for my Raspberry Pi 3b+ with an Preemptive RT Linux Kernel using Yocto Project's `warrior` branch.

I was able to create a base image for the same (`bitbake -k core-image-base`) and the Pi boots up well with the `PREEMPT RT` showing up when executing `uname -a`.

The image is about ~300MB big on an SD-Card that is 16GB. I wish to expand the SD Card completely in order to use the extra space.

#### Problem

1. Initially I found that `parted` isn't available as a binary on the base image hence I used `fdisk` as follows:

   ```
   fdisk -u /dev/mmcblk0
   ```

which provides me two partitions `mmcblk0p1` and `mmcblk0p2`

2. I delete partition 2 and create a new one with the start value as one normally does.
3. Upon writing the partition (`w` in `fdisk`) I get an `ioctl` Error stating `resource is busy`
4. I also do not have `resize2fs` available on the image. I only have a binary called `resize` which upon execution does not resize the SD Card even upon reboot.

Is there an alternative solution to resizing for Images creating using Yocto? There are no recipes for `raspi-config` which makes it difficult to have other tools to expand an SD Card.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot resize a mounted image.

The easiest approach would be to resize on another Linux system.

The traditional approach is described in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37744/8697 - this is effectively what `raspi-config` does, but if you don't have the standard Linux tools you would be out of luck.