# When I write a centos 7 img to my sd card why does it only use a tiny amount of space?

Tags: image

I have wrote the img using `raspberry pi imager`, with `dd` I  even tried formatting the fs to `ext4` then writing with `dd` and in all of my attempts it ends up only allocating 3.7GB.

My sd card is 64GB, can anyone help?

When the img is written it creates 3 partitions 1 ms-dos, 1 swap, and one for the os and everything else, the third one only has 3.7GB the other 2 much less.

So I created these partitions first then wrote to the partition using `dd` and the pi doesn't boot.

#### update

Unable to resize using `fdisk` already done those steps in the other answer. `parted` fails as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Mate not using all its storage](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37739/ubuntu-mate-not-using-all-its-storage) - although you need to use partition 3

Comment: no I have tried the exact same as that question woth `fdisk` and with `parted` but it didn't help.

Comment: There is no point saying "have tried the exact same" post what you did and any errors. I have done this dozens of times with different OS. You should include output of  fdisk -l for the relevant disk

Comment: @Milliways Quiet you, I've googled and struggled with the error messages for days. Have you tried this with Centos? just because you have tried it with many OSs doesn't mean you know it all. I figured it out, now get gone.

Comment: besides fdisk doesn't have an ext4 label which is what my fs is. Glad you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On centos seems you have to run this cmd on the pi:

`sudo /usr/bin/rootfs-expand`

Then all the space is filled.

Try parted and fdisk on the centos sd card all you want, have fun.